# Ionic read file from system and put it in canvas

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

Im trying to read file stored in file system (android) and then put the content into canvas using pdfjs library so I could render it in view. Idid the same with system pdf viewer and it worked, but I need to do later some painting on it and manupulation so it can't be dispsplayed in viewer, it must be within my app.

Rendering of my pdf works fine, since I have tested it with live reload mode.

Below is reading code

```
readFile( pathToFile ){
    this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl( pathToFile).then((fileEntry: any) => {
      fileEntry.file( (file) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend =  (event) => {
          const x = event.target as any;
          // let sliced = x._result.slice(x._result.indexOf(',') + 1, x._result.length);
          console.log('item', x)
          console.log('item', x.result)
          console.log('buffer',new Uint8Array(x.result))
          // console.log('64', new Uint8Array(x._result));
          // const bytes = this.base64ToUint8Array(sliced)
          this.renderPDF(x.result, this.container.nativeElement, 1)
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      });
    });
  }
```

here are the logs: 
[image]

as you can see pdf1 ist the last log so the promise from getDocument gets not resolved:

```
renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, scale) {
    console.log('pdf1')
    this.pdfCreator.disableWorker = true;
    this.pdfCreator
      .getDocument(url)
      .then((doc) => {
        this.doc = doc;
        console.log('pdf2')

        this.renderPages(canvasContainer, scale);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

I have spent two days on it without sccess...

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a canvas rather than a native pdf file reader?

Comment: yes, I have to have write object on it and manipulate them on the fly. This pdf file is just as a background I would say, a map of sort

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something went wrong with url,

Could you please try this

```
readFile( pathToFile ){
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl( pathToFile).then((fileEntry: any) => {
    fileEntry.file( (file) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend =  (event) => {
            const x = event.target as any;
            // let sliced = x._result.slice(x._result.indexOf(',') + 1, x._result.length);
            console.log('item', x)
            console.log('item', x.result)
            console.log('buffer',new Uint8Array(x.result))
            // console.log('64', new Uint8Array(x._result));
            // const bytes = this.base64ToUint8Array(sliced)
            var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(x.result)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            this.renderPDF(url, this.container.nativeElement, 1)
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
});
}
```